# salir al cielo - meaning

Tags: traducción, definiciones, méxico

I have heard the following line in the TV series Narcos:Mexico :

> Mañana me voy a cerrar un negocio. Ahí te aviso si todo sale al cielo.

Context: Felix, Guadalajara cartel boss, has just tried to renegotiate the terms of his cocaine transportation deal with the Cali cartel, but failed. After the meeting, he decides to travel the next day in order to get a new associate and a better deal. Then, he notifies his right-hand man (El Azul) of what he is going to do.

What does "sale al cielo" means? "to go alright" ? I couldn't find its meaning in the Word Reference dictionary.

Comment: not sure if it is everything goes fine, or goes away

Comment: I believe that I need the full context to understand it better

Comment: @Iria Context added. I don't think that "goes away" makes sense as a translation of "salir al cielo" in this sentence.

Comment: Note that many other answers of similar questions suggested explanations coming from the DAMER. Have you checked it?

Comment: as I said, I would like to know the full context, in Spanish a lot of words change their meaning due to the tone of the sentence, gestures and others. I meant goes away in the sense of the business ends up badly, e.g. police involved and 'sale al cielo', may mean, that the drugs goes away (se las llevan lejos)

Comment: I have not heard this expression anywhere so perhaps is a Mexico thing. I added México tag then.

Comment: BTW are you sure he said "al cielo" and not "al pelo" ???

Comment: @DGaleano Yes, I am sure he said "al cielo".

Comment: Did you have closed captions on in Spanish? There could be a transcription error or you could have misheard this.

Answer (score 3):

The actual coloquial idiom is:

> Mañana me voy a cerrar un negocio. Ahí te aviso si todo sale al ***cien***

which means "**100**", short for "**cien por ciento**" (*100% or a hundred percent*). The intended meaning being "*OK*" or "*all right*". Thusly this phrase would translate to:

> I'll be gone tomorrow, I'll be closing a deal. I'll let you know if everything went smoothly

The most frequent usage  of this regional slang when greeting someone:

| Spanish Mexican Slang | English Slang |
| --- | --- |
| - ¡*Quihubo*, ¿como estás, *loco*? - ¡Al cien, *ese*! | - 'sup, how are ya - A OK, *dude* |

It is also common to change cien for a similar sounding word, most notably "**ciego**" (*blind*), a common practice with slang colloquialisms, which i suspect is the case here, being very true to actual language use for the kind of character that utters this phrase.

A common usage of "**ciego**" is referring to MXN$ 100.00 banknotes, and an equivalent slang idiom in english would be "*c-note*" ( a USD$ 100.00 banknote ) as in:

> Los dulces valen un ciego, cada uno
> *(Candies are a c-note each)*

The slang meaning of **dulces** (*candies*) in this example is left as an exercise to the reader =)